# Using sed to replace string

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have below txt

```
604024692;-27.34
500570067;-.0835
604013284;0.00006
603839102;-.1121
```

I want it to be:

```
604024692;27.34
500570067;0.0835
604013284;0.00006
603839102;0.1121
```

but when I run below

```
sed 's/-/\0/'
```

it gives me

```
604024692;027.34
500570067;0.0835
604013284;0.00006
603839102;0.1121
```

I am using AIX 7.1 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one-liner may help:

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=";" '{sub(/^-/,"0",$2);$2+=0}7' file
```

The idea is, after substitution, we let awk handle the leading zero.

With your data as example:

```
kent$  cat f
604024692;-27.34
500570067;-.0835

kent$  awk -F';' -v OFS=";" '{sub(/^-/,"0",$2);$2+=0}7' f
604024692;27.34
500570067;0.0835
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked but introduce another issue. I have `604013284;0.00006` in my file and this was turned to `604013284;6e-05`

Comment: when you ask a question here, please list all your requirements in the question, do NOT put them in comments.

Comment: @Drsin and what version of awk do you use? here with gawk, `0.00006` was changed into `6e-05` automatically.  Anyway, you can output `$2` with `printf "%g",$2` to achieve it. Do some test you will see.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {$2=($2<0?-$2:$2)}1' file
604024692;27.34
500570067;0.0835
604013284;0.00006
603839102;0.1121
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below sed command.

```
$ sed 's/-//g;s/\(^\|;\)\./\10./g' file
604024692;27.34
500570067;0.0835
```

`s/-//g`, removes all the minus symbols. `s/\(^\|;\)\./\10.` matches the dot which are at the start or the dot which are next to the semicolon and replaces the match with the chars inside the group index 1 plus the digit `0` plus a dot.

Comment: @Raj, Thanks. Yours also work but created another issue. I have updated my initial post. See above.

Comment: @Drsin what do you mean? my code works for the above updated input